# How to resolve error 'While executing gem ... (TypeError) can't convert nil into String'?

Tags: ruby, windows, drupal, rubygems

I am using using Windows 8 with cygwin. I am trying to configure Omega4 Drupal theme.

I have ruby version 1.9.3p547  (2014-05-14 revision 45962) [x86_64-cygwin]

I have installed ruby gems version 2.4.1 from https://rubygems.org/ , as shown also when I run the `gem -v` command:

```
$ gem -v
2.4.1
```

I have Drupal installed in folder c:\xampp\htdocs\drupal , and cygwin is accessible by cygdrive.

I navigate to the folder of my subtheme and then run the command like so:

```
$ drush omega-guard

which: no tput in (/home/prem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@omega.furniure/bin:/home/               prem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@global/bin:/home/prem/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547                                                /bin:/home/prem/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client:/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/Windows:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/OpenCL SDK/3.0/bin/x86:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/OpenCL SDK/3.0/bin/x64:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin:/cygdrive/c/Ruby200-x64/bin:/cygdrive/c/Ruby193/bin:       /cygdrive/c/ProgramData/Drush:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Drush/GnuWin32/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Drush/Php:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Drush/cwRsync/bin:/cygdrive/c/xampp/php)
Which theme do you want to run Guard for?
 [0]  :  Cancel
 [1]  :  furniure (Subtheme of Omega) - Please provide a description for your
         theme.
 [2]  :  Ohm (Subtheme of Omega) - Omega based demonstration theme. Serves as a
         best-practice reference for the Omega documentation. Ohm will be
         constantly updated as best practice evolves so shouldn't be used in
         production.
 [3]  :  Omega - A powerful HTML5 base theme framework utilizing tools like
         Sass, Compass, Grunt, Bower, Ruby Version Manager, Bundler and more.
1
There was a problem with your setup:                                     [error]
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler can't satisfy your Gemfile's dependencies.
Install missing gems with `bundle install`.
```

However when I run the below command I run into an error I don't understand:

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using addressable 2.3.6

TypeError: can't convert nil into String
An error occurred while installing sass (3.4.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install sass -v '3.4.1'` succeeds before bundling.

$ gem install sass -v 3.4.1

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
    can't convert nil into String
```

So my question is about the above error `While executing gem ... (TypeError) can't convert nil into String`: how can I resolve this error?

Comment: Can some one please provide some help. Its really very urgent for me.

Comment: I have solved it by self. I have uninstalled the ruby , rvm, ruby gems from mysystem. and Again installed the recent version of all softwares. Its working now. 
Thanks for all viewing this issue.